# Custom taxonomy not showing in grid view for 'attachment' post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy, media-library

I've added a taxonomy called 'colors' to the built-in attachment post type. I can see the taxonomy when editing an item the 'list' view, but when using the 'grid' view, I can't see/use the terms of the taxonomy.

List view:
[image: list view]

Grid view:
[image: grid view]

I want the taxonomy to show up in the grid view as well, but can't figure out why it's not doing that.

This is my code for registering the custom taxonomy:

```
function nij_register_taxonomies() {
    $taxonomy_names = array(
        'singular' => __( 'Color', 'stufig' ),
        'plural'   => __( 'Colors', 'stufig' )
    );

    register_taxonomy( strtolower($taxonomy_names['singular']),
        array('attachment'),
        array(
            'labels'            => array(
                'name'              => sprintf( _x( '%s', 'taxonomy general name', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['plural'] ),
                'singular_name'     => sprintf( _x( '%s', 'taxonomy singular name', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'search_items'      => sprintf( __( 'Search %s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['plural'] ),
                'all_items'         => sprintf( __( 'All %s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['plural'] ),
                'parent_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Parent %s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'parent_item_colon' => sprintf( __( 'Parent %s:', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'edit_item'         => sprintf( __( 'Edit %s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'update_item'       => sprintf( __( 'Update %s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'add_new_item'      => sprintf( __( 'Add New %s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'new_item_name'     => sprintf( __( 'New %s Name', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['singular'] ),
                'menu_name'         => sprintf( __( '%s', 'stufig' ), $taxonomy_names['plural'] )
            ),
            'public'            => false,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => false,
            'update_count_callback' => '_update_generic_term_count',
            // 'rewrite'           => array(),
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'nij_register_taxonomies', 11 );
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Artwork` checkbox?

Comment: The artwork checkbox has been added with Advanced Custom Fields, there's no actual code for it. I have checked the view with my custom theme and ACF disabled (and the color taxonomy added through a plugin), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the argument `public` to `true` will do. Check out the file `wp-admin/includes/media.php`, function `get_compat_media_markup()` for reference:

```
if ( $args['in_modal'] ) {
    foreach ( get_attachment_taxonomies( $post ) as $taxonomy ) {
        $t = (array) get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );

        if ( ! $t['public'] || ! $t['show_ui'] ) {
            continue;
        }
```

Comment: After changing the 'public' value to true, the taxonomy pops up in the modal, but it shows up as a text field.

Comment: Apparently this is due to a bug that's in WordPress since version 3.5. I ended up using a taxonomy field from Advanced Custom Fields. I've hidden the taxonomy input in the grid library and hidden the ACF field in the list view.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22938) to the thread, by the way.